# ListItem text keeps changing back

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in `AlerDialog` (as single choice, with radio buttons). This `ListView` has assigned `OnItemClickListener` which gets `TextView` from the item and changes its text.

```java
final ListView lv = dialog.getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        final TextView tv = (TextView) view;
        tv.setText("a");
    }
});
```

It works fine on my Android 4.2, as I click items, it changes their text to *a*. But on my colleague's 2.3, it has the following weird behaviour: When he click on some item, the text changes to *a*. But when he click on some other item, the text changes back to original value. And no, I'm not manipulating the text anywhere else.

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: I didn't coded any adapter. I just used `AlertDialog.Builder` [setSingleChoiceItems](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) method with `String` array and empty `OnClickListener` (because I'm setting it later with some more complex code which needs finished `AlertDialog`).

Comment: without adapter listview? how?

Comment: I guess it gets automaticaly created by the builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution!

I have to edit the array I used in `setSingleChoiceItems()`, and then call

```
((ArrayAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```